# How to compare one element from same table to another element

Tags: php

Suppose the there is `chemical table` and having **4 records**.

```
chemical_name = c1,c2,c3,c4
```

I need to look **output table** like this in table form

```
chemical one       chemical two
c1                    c2
c1                    c3
c1                    c4
c2                    c3
c2                    c4
c3                    c4
```

How can I do this in **php**?

Give the suggestion to me

Comment: Is 'chemical' a MySQL database table? If so you can get this by query

Comment: It is a postgresql table. If possible please tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr><th>Chemical One</th><th>Chemical two</th></tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";
    $chemical=array('c1','c2','c3','c4');
    $count_chem=count($chemical);
    for ($i=0; $i <= $count_chem; $i++) { 

            for ($j=$i+1; $j < $count_chem; $j++) { 
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$chemical[$i]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$chemical[$j]."</td>";

                echo "<tr>";
            }
    }
    echo "</tbody></table>";
?>
```

try this one and let me know if any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following query to get this output:

```
SELECT ch1.chemical, ch2.chemical 
FROM chemical ch1
JOIN chemical ch2 
ON ch1.chemical < ch2.chemical
ORDER BY ch1.chemical, ch2.chemical  ASC
```